# How to tell the difference between a SP Online drive and a Teams channel-drive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams

Using the MSFT Graph API, is there a way to differentiate Drives (which are documentLibraries) that are used for Team-Channels versus those that are "simply" documentLibraries created WRT a more generic, SharePoint Online Site?

Retrieving a user's /v1.0/sites?search=* returns a union of SPO Sites the user is a member of and Teams the user is a member of. (Yes, Teams are SPO sites or libraries within a site natively.)

I need to differentiate either the Sites by whether or not they're a Team-Site (because I can then filter Drives returned), or specifically all the Drives returned to differentiate whether the Drive is a Channel-Drive or simply a plain-old documentLibrary that is part of a Site.

Retrieving Sites from Graph shows no apparent properties that indicate what "type" of Site it is, and neither do the Drives queried from each Site (/v1.0/sites/SITE-ID/drives).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way can be check the `owner` of the `drive` associated with the `site`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}?$expand=drive
```

That endpoint will return `site` info including `drive` info

```
{
"description": "...",
"id": "xxx",
...
"drive": {
    "description": "",
    "id": "xxx",
    "driveType": "documentLibrary",
    ...
    "owner": {
        "group": {
            "email": "xxx",
            "id": "42857780-3ab6-412d-a9b8-5e6adc73aabb",
            "displayName": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "quota": {}
}
```

If the `owner` has property group then you can use group id in the following endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(id,resourceProvisioningOptions)/$entity",
    "id": "xxx",
    "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
        "Team"
    ]
}
```

select `resourceProvisioningOptions` which specifies the group resources that are provisioned as part of Microsoft 365 group creation, that are not normally part of default group creation. If one of the value is Team then the drive is used for teams.

Resources:

[group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)